# Moz API getting information via jQuery .Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having issues getting data back from the moz api using php and ajax. I would like the user to be able to enter a url and then have a function that replaces a divs html. the hello.php is from the Moz Api. I'm using MAMP and my code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>hello from gulp automation tool</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <label for="url">Enter URL:</label><input value="" type="url" name="url" id="url"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Get URL Metrics!"/>
    </form>

    <div class="info">

    </div>
</div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataUrl = $('form input[type=url]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "hello.php",
        type: "POST",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dataUrl,
        success: function(response){
            $('.info').html(
                response[0].pda
            );
        }
    });
});
});
 </script>
```

Below is the code that is in the hello.php file.

```
<?php

// Add your accessID here
$AccessID = 'mozscape-a034cdc391';
// Add your secretKey here
$SecretKey = '6ac62e3e6df3ad617c7cf3fef891df9d';
// Set the rate limit
$expires = time() + 300;
// Put each parameter on a new line.
$stringToSign = $accessID."\n".$expires;
// Get the "raw" or binary output of the hmac hash.
$binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $stringToSign, $secretKey, true);
// Base64-encode it and then url-encode that.
$urlSafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
// Add up all the bit flags you want returned.
// Learn more here: https://moz.com/help/guides/moz-api/mozscape/api-reference/url-metrics
$cols = "68719476736";
// Put it all together and you get your request URL.


 $requestUrl = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/?      Cols=".$cols."&AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expires."&Signature=".$urlSafeSig    nature;
// Put your URLS into an array and json_encode them.
$batchedDomains = array($_POST['data']);
$encodedDomains = json_encode($batchedDomains);
// Use Curl to send off your request.
// Send your encoded list of domains through Curl's POSTFIELDS.
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $encodedDomains
);
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
$contents = json_decode($content);
print_r($contents);
?>
```

Comment: Could you make "I'm having issues" more specific? What exactly is your problem? Can you share error messages?

Comment: I'm not getting any data back from the api, that is my biggest issue. I'm not getting any error messages, after the submit button is pressed, nothing happens.